# Insert a copy of a string(no particular string in mind to find) right after the string

Tags: regex, vim, grep, notepad++

So, I am learning to manipulate strings using regex in text editors, and I wanted to know how to make a copy of a string and insert that copy right after the first string

When I say to insert a copy of a string right after the same string, I mean to insert a copy of the string insert, without specifying it's particular identity, right after it.

e.g Given the string

### "So, I am learning to manipulate strings using regex in text editors"

I would like to be able to, using regex, transform it to

### "So So, I am learning to manipulate strings using regex in text editors"

Now, for those who think it is a no-brainer, please make certain to read the part where I state that I am learning this . . . If you feel this is below your level, it is ok to skip posting your comments or response on this, please.

Comment: an examle would be better.

Comment: No offense intended, but do you know **anything** about regexes?  Because this is bone-basic stuff.  Spend ten minutes reading the tool's docs/help files and you should be able to answer this yourself.

Comment: @AvinashRaj, an example of what?

Comment: could you provide a sample input along with the expected output which reflects [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26447532/insert-a-copy-of-a-string-right-after-the-string?noredirect=1#comment41538696_26447677) comment.

Comment: We are actually trying to help, but we need to know what tool/flavor you're using, and your tags are getting in the way.  Notepad++ and vim are editors that both support regex substitutions, but with extremely different syntax and capabilities; grep is a command-line tool that doesn't do substitutions; and nsregularexpression is the name of a class in an Objective-C framework published by Apple.  I recommend you stick with Notepad++ for the moment; as of version 6 it uses the PCRE library, which is the most widely supported/compatible flavor out there.

Answer (score 1):

In vim you can make a search and substitute:

```
:%s/\(textpattern\)/\1\1/g
```

Where `\1` contains the text inside `\(` and `\)`.

I don't know how to do the same in notepadd++.

Comment: +1. Also notice the different group syntax (escaped parentheses) - that's the difference between POSIX regex, that vim uses, and PCRE (which implements Perl-style syntax) that most of the others use.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not using Vim at this time. I tried this :%s/\((\w)\)/\1\1/g  in Notepad++ and Sublime3 and I still do not get the replace I need

Answer (score 1):

You want to create a [group and then use a backrefrence](http://vimregex.com/#backreferences) in the replacement string.

So if you ran `:s/\(Hello\)/\1\1/` on:

```
Hello, World!
```

You should get

```
HelloHello, World!
```

The backreference `\0` always references the entire match so you could write this more simply as `:s/Hello/\0\0` and get the same result.

The above is for Vim.  In grep the `/` is not used on the grouping, but the back reference is the same.  You can search on back references in your different editors to see which syntax they use.

Comment: I tried this too but I don't think I have it right either. I can capture the first word on each line using ^(\w)*. With this, I don't need to know the identity of the string that is at the start of the line. But when I tried your example up there using :s/(\w)*/\0\0, I got weird stuff instead

Comment: Sorry I messed up the formatting and the backslash before the closing parentheses wasn't being displayed.  I've updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are wanting to use a [capturing group](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-capture.html) to recall what was matched ...

Capturing groups could be used later on in the regular expression as a backreference to what was matched in that captured group. They are created by placing the characters to be grouped inside a set of parentheses `( )`. A backreference is specified as a backslash (`\`) followed by a digit indicating the number of the group to be recalled.

Below is an example using Notepad++ ...

```
Find: (foo)
Replace: \1-\1
```

So `\1` is the backreference of the matched group, the first three characters "foo".

Comment: I am not trying to specify the string itself. I need to be able to catch the string(whatever it is) and then add a duplicate of it right after.

Comment: I don't seem to get it still please. Eg. I am able to capture the first word on each line using ^(\w)*, but when I try to do a replace with \1-\1, I don't get the desired result. Instead the editor instead duplicates the last letter of the string, inserts a dash between them, and replaces my matched string with it.

Answer (score 1):

How about (for Notepad++):

Find what: `^(\w+)`
Replace with: `$1 $1`

Where:

Regex part:

```
^     : begining of line
(     : start capture group 1
  \w+ : one or more word character, ie. [a-zA-Z0-9_]
)     : end of group 1
```

Replace part:

```
$1    : content of group 1
      : a space
$1    : content of group 1
```

Comment: In particular, notice how the quantifier (`+`) is *inside* the parentheses.  In comments under other answers, you said you used `^(\w)*`, which captures one character at a time in the same group, each time overwriting the previously captured character.